# Python Counter too slow

Tags: python-3.x

I just wanted to code a little timer on my work pc. Funny thing is, the counter is too slow, meaning it runs longer than it should. I am really confused. The delay grows the smaller the intervals of updating become. Is my pc too slow? The CPU is around 30% while running this... idk.
    python3.6.3

```
import time
def timer(sec):
    start = sec
    print(sec)
    while sec > 0:
        sec = sec-0.1            #the smaller this value, the slower
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(round(sec,2))
print("Done! {} Seconds passed.".format(start))



start = time.time()          #For Testing
timer(10)
print(time.time()-start)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sleeping you process require a system call (a call to the kernel, which triggers an hardware interruption to give hand to that kernel), and a hardware clock interruption to wake up the process once it's done.  Sleeping may not be a lot of CPU computations, but waiting for the hardware interruption and the kernel to task the processes can take multiple CPU cycles.

Rather than waiting for a constant unit of time, I suggest you to wait for the time required to hit the next milestone (by getting the current time, rounding it to the next step and getting the difference)

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the scheduler : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you can use normal operators on `time.time()`

```
import time

start = time.time()

seconds = 5

while True:
  if start - time.time() > seconds:
    print(seconds + " elapsed.")
```